# SP 2010 Debuging problem

Tags: error, development, visual-studio, powershell

Please HELP,
I creating custom SP2010 intranet site for last few months. During development i didn't have any particular problem with debuging except this one and now I can't figure where's the catch.

In last five days I didn't do any significant modification on code in solution but I installed CSKDev and PowerGUi extensions to VS 2010. Also i tried developer dashboard feature. 
And now I have terrible problem with debuging:

a) While I try to "Attach to process" it is impossible for VS 2010 (Premium) to get to the breakpoint; 
b) While I try to go with classic debug (F5) solution startup go for eternity and as it seems it(SP solution) want to pull ALL .dlls from GAC (not just its). Of course after certain time IIS says "timeout"(cca 3 min) and that's it.

During "trying" period of debug, of course SP UI is barely accessible.

To fix that - I uninstalled all extensions, i tried with IISreset, rebooting pc and nothing helps even little bit. 
My idea: Some extension corrupted SP app pool or some VS debug property but I can't find what.

Does somebody experience similar and please can somebody put the finger to possible right answer??

Comment: Is this happening with any project you develop within any site collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank God, I found answer. There wasn't problem in extensions, it was in "bad" breakpoints.
In five years of development I never heard about that but even that is, as it seems, possible.

Link with description:

http://darrinbishop.com/blog/archive/2010/06/24/156.aspx